# Trying to get direct, indirect, intersecting routes for public transport using an sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to build a query get a route from A to B.  There could be sometimes a direct route, some times I need to find the intersection and get the exchange route.  The objective is let a person to travel from A to B and give the different Mode Types, and the routes.  I will add the shortest or best route later but for now just to get the correct route.  The issue is when I try to get the intersecting route.  Somehow I feel there should be an easier way to get this done.  I hope this not too much of code.

The logic that I think should work is

1. Find the starting route (Halts table), if we have one get the RouteID and route number, if we cannot find a starting route try to get the next nearest route.
2. Find the ending route.  If we have one, check if the starting route is within this route (this is for a direct route), if yes get the RouteID and route number and insert into a temp table to show the final route.

   3. If point 2 does not have an ending route try to find an intersecting routes from the starting point and find if we have any routes that intersect, if yes get that route id and route number.  From the intersecting route try if we can reach the end route `this is where I got lost as there can be more than one intersecting route`

**RouteTypes Table**

This table has the different route types like City Buses, Long Distance Buses, Local Trains, Long Distance Trains, Domestic Flights, International Flights

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RouteTypes](
    [RouteTypeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ModeTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RouteType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RouteTypes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RouteTypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**ModeTypes Table**

This table will hold the different Transportation types like Bus, Train, Flights

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ModeTypes](
    [ModeTypeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ModeType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ModeTypes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ModeTypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Halts Table**

This table will hold all the halts and is a master table of halts

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Halts](
    [HaltID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Halt] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Routes Table**

This table will have the route number some.  Since I am not too clear on what needs to be add here most of the fields I am not using as of now

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Routes](
    [RouteID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RouteTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RouteNo] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Duration] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Distance] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [OldRouteNo] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [DaysAvailable] [char](15) NULL,
    [IsEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [BeginAt] [time](7) NULL,
    [EndAt] [time](7) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Routes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RouteID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Route Halts table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RouteHalts](
    [RouteHaltID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RouteID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstLastHalt] [char](1) NULL,
    [HaltNo] [smallint] NULL,
    [HaltID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RouteHalts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RouteHaltID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am using a stored procedure and this is what  I have got so far.  The results do not some correctly when I get the inspecting route.

```
DECLARE @StartingRouteID int;
    DECLARE @EndingRouteID int;
    DECLARE @CrossRouteHalt  nvarchar(100);

    CREATE TABLE #TmpStartingRoute  
            (  
            ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            RouteID int null,
            RouteNo nvarchar(60) null,
            RouteType nvarchar(100) null,
            Duration nvarchar(60) null,
            Distance nvarchar(60) null,
            DaysAvailable nvarchar(60) null,
            Halt nvarchar(100) null,
            ModeType nvarchar(100) null
            )

      CREATE TABLE #TmpStartingHalts  
            (  
            ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            RouteID int null,     
            RouteNo nvarchar(60) null,
            RouteType nvarchar(100) null,
            Duration nvarchar(60) null,
            Distance nvarchar(60) null,
            DaysAvailable nvarchar(60) null,
            Halt nvarchar(100) null,
            ModeType nvarchar(100) null
            )


    CREATE TABLE #TmpEndingRoute  
            (  
            ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            RouteID int null,
            RouteNo nvarchar(60) null,
            RouteType nvarchar(100) null,
            Duration nvarchar(60) null,
            Distance nvarchar(60) null,
            DaysAvailable nvarchar(60) null,
            Halt nvarchar(100) null,
            ModeType nvarchar(100) null
            )

             CREATE TABLE #TmpEndingHalts  
            (  
            ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            RouteID int null,
            RouteNo nvarchar(60) null,
            RouteType nvarchar(100) null,
            Duration nvarchar(60) null,
            Distance nvarchar(60) null,
            DaysAvailable nvarchar(60) null,
            Halt nvarchar(100) null,
            ModeType nvarchar(100) null
            )


    CREATE TABLE #TmpRts  
            (  
            ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            RouteID int null,
            Halt nvarchar(100) null,
            RouteNo nvarchar(60) null,
            RouteType nvarchar(100) null,
            ModeType nvarchar(100) null
            )

     CREATE TABLE #TmpIntersection  
            (  
            ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            RouteID int null,
            Halt nvarchar(100) null,
            RouteNo nvarchar(60) null,
            RouteType nvarchar(100) null,
            ModeType nvarchar(100) null
            )

    CREATE TABLE #FinalRoute  
            (  
            ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            RouteID int null,
            RouteNo nvarchar(60) null,
            Halt nvarchar(100) null,
            RouteType nvarchar(100) null,
            ModeType nvarchar(100) null

            )


    -- Check if Starting point exits
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM RouteHalts where Halt like'%'+ @StartingPoint +'%') 
        BEGIN
            SELECT 
                @StartingRouteID=R.RouteID
            from 
                ModeTypes M
            inner join 
                RouteTypes RT on M.ModeTypeID=RT.ModeTypeID
            inner join 
                Routes R on RT.RouteTypeID=R.RouteTypeID
            inner join 
                RouteHalts RH on R.RouteID=RH.RouteID
            where 
                RH.Halt like'%'+ @StartingPoint +'%'

            insert into #TmpStartingRoute(RouteID,RouteNo,RouteType,Duration,Distance,DaysAvailable,Halt,ModeType)
                SELECT 
                    R.RouteID, R.RouteNo,RT.RouteType,R.Duration,R.Distance,R.DaysAvailable, RH.Halt,M.ModeType
                from 
              ModeTypes M
                inner join 
                    RouteTypes RT on M.ModeTypeID=RT.ModeTypeID
                inner join 
                    Routes R on RT.RouteTypeID=R.RouteTypeID
                inner join 
                    RouteHalts RH on R.RouteID=RH.RouteID
                where 
                    RH.Halt like'%'+ @StartingPoint +'%'
                order by 
                    R.RouteNo,RH.HaltNo

             -- Insert halts of starting routes
             insert into #TmpStartingHalts(RouteID,RouteNo,RouteType,Duration,Distance,DaysAvailable,Halt,ModeType)
                SELECT 
                    R.RouteID, R.RouteNo,RT.RouteType,R.Duration,R.Distance,R.DaysAvailable, RH.Halt,M.ModeType 
                from 
                    ModeTypes M
                inner join 
                    RouteTypes RT on M.ModeTypeID=RT.ModeTypeID
                inner join 
                    Routes R on RT.RouteTypeID=R.RouteTypeID
                inner join 
                    RouteHalts RH on R.RouteID=RH.RouteID
                where 
                    RH.RouteID=@StartingRouteID and  RH.Halt not like'%'+ @StartingPoint +'%'
                order by 
                    R.RouteNo,RH.HaltNo


        END

    ELSE

        -- Find the closest locaton of the starting point
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('No Routes Available', 16, 2)
            RETURN
        END

    -- Check if Ending point exits within the start route to get the direct route
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM RouteHalts R INNER JOIN #TmpStartingRoute SR on R.RouteID=SR.RouteID
            where R.Halt like'%'+ @EndingPoint +'%') 
        BEGIN
           print 'In End route exists within starting route'

            SELECT 
                @EndingRouteID= R.RouteID
            from 
                ModeTypes M
            inner join 
                RouteTypes RT on M.ModeTypeID=RT.ModeTypeID
            inner join 
                Routes R on RT.RouteTypeID=R.RouteTypeID
            inner join 
                RouteHalts RH on R.RouteID=RH.RouteID
            INNER JOIN
                #TmpStartingRoute SR on R.RouteID=SR.RouteID
            where 
                RH.Halt like'%'+ @EndingPoint +'%'
             insert into #TmpEndingRoute(RouteID,RouteNo,RouteType,Duration,Distance,DaysAvailable,Halt,ModeType)
            SELECT 
                R.RouteID,R.RouteNo, RT.RouteType,R.Duration,R.Distance,R.DaysAvailable, RH.Halt,M.ModeType 
            from 
                ModeTypes M
            inner join 
                RouteTypes RT on M.ModeTypeID=RT.ModeTypeID
            inner join 
                Routes R on RT.RouteTypeID=R.RouteTypeID
            inner join 
                RouteHalts RH on R.RouteID=RH.RouteID
            INNER JOIN
                #TmpStartingRoute SR on R.RouteID=SR.RouteID
            where 
                RH.Halt like'%'+ @EndingPoint +'%'
            order by 
                R.RouteNo,RH.HaltNo

            -- Insert all halts of ending route 
             insert into #TmpEndingHalts(RouteID,RouteNo,RouteType,Duration,Distance,DaysAvailable,Halt,ModeType)
            SELECT 
                R.RouteID,R.RouteNo, RT.RouteType,R.Duration,R.Distance,R.DaysAvailable, RH.Halt,M.ModeType 
            from 
                ModeTypes M
            inner join 
                RouteTypes RT on M.ModeTypeID=RT.ModeTypeID
            inner join 
                Routes R on RT.RouteTypeID=R.RouteTypeID
            inner join 
                RouteHalts RH on R.RouteID=RH.RouteID
            where 
               RH.RouteID=@EndingRouteID and RH.Halt not like'%'+ @EndingPoint +'%'
            order by 
                R.RouteNo,RH.HaltNo


        delete from #TmpStartingHalts where RouteID not in (select RouteID from #TmpEndingRoute)
        delete from #TmpStartingRoute where RouteID not in (select RouteID from #TmpEndingRoute)
        select * from #TmpEndingRoute
        END


    ELSE

        -- Find the closest locaton of the starting point
        BEGIN
            print 'In End route does NOT exists within starting route'
           SELECT 
                @EndingRouteID= R.RouteID
            from 
                ModeTypes M
            inner join 
                RouteTypes RT on M.ModeTypeID=RT.ModeTypeID
            inner join 
                Routes R on RT.RouteTypeID=R.RouteTypeID
            inner join 
                RouteHalts RH on R.RouteID=RH.RouteID

            where 
                RH.Halt like'%'+ @EndingPoint +'%'
             insert into #TmpEndingRoute(RouteID,RouteNo,RouteType,Duration,Distance,DaysAvailable,Halt,ModeType)
            SELECT 
                R.RouteID,R.RouteNo, RT.RouteType,R.Duration,R.Distance,R.DaysAvailable, RH.Halt,M.ModeType 
            from 
                ModeTypes M
            inner join 
                RouteTypes RT on M.ModeTypeID=RT.ModeTypeID
            inner join 
                Routes R on RT.RouteTypeID=R.RouteTypeID
            inner join 
                RouteHalts RH on R.RouteID=RH.RouteID

            where 
                RH.Halt like'%'+ @EndingPoint +'%'
            order by 
                R.RouteNo,RH.HaltNo

            -- Insert all halts of ending route 
             insert into #TmpEndingHalts(RouteID,RouteNo,RouteType,Duration,Distance,DaysAvailable,Halt,ModeType)
            SELECT 
                R.RouteID,R.RouteNo, RT.RouteType,R.Duration,R.Distance,R.DaysAvailable, RH.Halt,M.ModeType 
            from 
                ModeTypes M
            inner join 
                RouteTypes RT on M.ModeTypeID=RT.ModeTypeID
            inner join 
                Routes R on RT.RouteTypeID=R.RouteTypeID
            inner join 
                RouteHalts RH on R.RouteID=RH.RouteID
            where 
               RH.RouteID=@EndingRouteID and RH.Halt not like'%'+ @EndingPoint +'%'
            order by 
                R.RouteNo,RH.HaltNo
        END

    -- Get the intersection Routes
        insert into #TmpRts(RouteID,Halt,RouteNo,RouteType,ModeType)
       select RH.RouteID,RH.halt,TER.RouteNo,TER.RouteType,TER.ModeType
        from 
            RouteHalts RH
        INNER JOIN 
            #TmpEndingRoute TER on RH.RouteID=TER.RouteID 

    -- Get the intersection Halt
    IF EXISTS( select 1 from RouteHalts RH INNER JOIN #TmpRts TER on TER.Halt=RH.Halt
            where RH.RouteID in (select RouteID from #TmpStartingRoute))
            begin
            print 'in exists'
        select 
            @CrossRouteHalt= TER.Halt 
        from 
            RouteHalts RH
        INNER JOIN 
            #TmpRts TER on TER.Halt=RH.Halt
        where RH.RouteID in (select RouteID from #TmpStartingRoute)

        -- Insert into #TmpIntersection 
        insert into #TmpIntersection(RouteID,Halt,RouteNo,RouteType,ModeType)
        select RH.RouteID,RH.Halt,RouteNo,RouteType,ModeType 
        from 
            RouteHalts RH
        INNER JOIN 
            #TmpRts TER on TER.Halt=RH.Halt
            where RH.RouteID in (select RouteID from #TmpStartingRoute)
        end
   -- If no intersection halt exsits then try to get the matching routes from the starting point halts
    IF not EXISTS( select 1 from RouteHalts RH INNER JOIN #TmpRts TER on TER.Halt=RH.Halt
            where RH.RouteID in (select RouteID from #TmpStartingRoute))
        begin
            print 'in not exists'

            insert into #TmpRts(RouteID,Halt,RouteNo)
            select distinct RH.RouteID,RH.halt,TSR.RouteNo
            from
                RouteHalts RH
            INNER JOIN 
                #TmpStartingHalts TSR on RH.Halt=TSR.Halt

            -- Update the Route type to show the current route type of the connecting routes
            update TER
            set TER.RouteType =  RT.RouteType, TER.ModeType=MT.ModeType
                from  #TmpRts TER
            INNER JOIN Routes R on TER.RouteID=R.RouteID
            inner join 
                RouteTypes RT on R.RouteTypeID=RT.RouteTypeID
            inner join 
                ModeTypes MT on RT.ModeTypeID=MT.ModeTypeID

            select 
                @CrossRouteHalt= TSR.Halt 
            from 
                RouteHalts RH
            INNER JOIN 
                #TmpRts TSR on TSR.Halt=RH.Halt
            where RH.RouteID in (select RouteID from #TmpStartingHalts)

            -- Insert into #TmpIntersection 
        insert into #TmpIntersection(RouteID,Halt,RouteNo,RouteType,ModeType)
        select RH.RouteID,RH.Halt,RouteNo,RouteType,ModeType 
        from 
            RouteHalts RH
        INNER JOIN 
            #TmpRts TSR on TSR.Halt=RH.Halt
            where RH.RouteID in (select RouteID from #TmpStartingHalts)
        end



    /*
        Insert all data in to #FinalRoute
    */

    -- Insert the Starting Route record
    insert into #FinalRoute(RouteID,Halt,RouteNo,RouteType,ModeType)
    select RouteID,Halt,RouteNo,RouteType,ModeType from #TmpStartingRoute

    -- Insert the Intersection Halt
    insert into #FinalRoute(Halt)
    select @CrossRouteHalt

    -- Get the new Starting point 
    delete from #TmpRts where routeid in (select routeid from #TmpStartingRoute)
    select RH.RouteID,RH.halt,R.RouteNo,TER.RouteType,TER.ModeType
    into #TmpNewStartingPoint
        from 
            RouteHalts RH
        INNER JOIN 
            #TmpRts TER on RH.RouteID=TER.RouteID and TER.RouteID not in (select routeid from #TmpEndingRoute)
        inner join Routes R on TER.RouteID=R.RouteID and TER.RouteID not in (select routeid from #TmpEndingRoute)


    /*
        Insert all data in to #FinalRoute
    */


    -- Check if #TmpNewStartingPoint is empty then add the insersection route from #TmpRts else add the data from #TmpNewStartingPoint
    IF NOT EXISTS(select 1 from #TmpNewStartingPoint) 
    BEGIN
        print 'in no new starting point'
        insert into #FinalRoute(RouteID,Halt,RouteNo,RouteType,ModeType)
        select RouteID, Halt,RouteNo,RouteType,ModeType from  #TmpRts where Halt=@CrossRouteHalt 

    END

    IF EXISTS(select 1 from #TmpNewStartingPoint) 

    BEGIN
        print 'in new starting point'
        insert into #FinalRoute(RouteID,Halt,RouteNo,RouteType,ModeType)
        select RouteID,Halt,RouteNo,RouteType,ModeType from #TmpNewStartingPoint where halt in (select halt from #TmpEndingHalts)

    END

    -- Insert the Ending Route record
    insert into #FinalRoute(RouteID,Halt,RouteNo,RouteType,ModeType)
    select RouteID,Halt,RouteNo,RouteType,ModeType from #TmpEndingRoute

    select * from #FinalRoute
```

**Edit 1**
I found these link to be interesting so adding it here

[This link is something similar to what I am trying to do](http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html#dijkstra)

Comment: This is a massive problem which we could only scratch the surface of in an answer here; hence my 'too broad' close vote.

Comment: @AakashM I am still trying to find if there is an easier way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create a network grid with travel cost so you solve the traveling using a `Travel Salesman Promblem` algorithm like `djistra`  or `short A*`

In my case I use postgres lib `PgRouting` http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/shortest_path.html#

In the graph

- red mean subway route
- green mean highway route
- green dot mean starting point a
- blue dot mean end point
- yellow dot mean train station. And usually end/start in a road link so you can make route transition.

Links

- Road will have some speed like 60-80 kmh
- Roads also have a walking speed of 3kmh
- Train a constant speed of 60 kmh

This way you use the TSP algorithm to optimize costs. You asign a cost using each speed to calculate `Time = Distance / Speed` or calculate only `distance`. Also you can change the grid in the `select` before using the algorithm like ignore bus routes. Or alter the road speed using real time traffic

[image]

Comment: Looking at it is confusing now.  But will try out and add an update here

Comment: I am accepting this answer as I got a clue on how to proceed :)